# When I disable network adapter and re-enable it now it requires restart, how to fix this?

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter

I have 2 networks in my house, wired and wireless. To access the wireless I need to disable the wired adapter.

For years it worked with no problems, all network adapters could be enabled, disabled, re-enabled and they worked without restart required.

Suddenly, when I now disable and re-enable my network adapter I get weird behavior. The icon of the connection stays gray and disabled. The status icon in tray shows no Internet access. I need to restart the system to regain access to my network.

I have no idea what caused it, I can only suspect Android SDK and Android emulator installed. I have also Hyper-V configured and virtual adapters always on.

How to restore normal Windows operation, so the restarts wouldn't be required?

Comment: Did you check what your network configuration looks like after you disable the adapter? Maybe the other adapter only gets an APIPA address and you'd just need to run a renew?

Comment: The problem is now when I touch anything in my network configuration - my Windows almost immediately crashes the hard way. Sound hangs like broken CD, mouse cursor freezes, nothing works but hard reset. After a few like this I gave up to touch it.

Comment: If that's is the case something in your system is probably broken as it is a really uncommon behavior. Either your host system itself or your virtualization solution is broken. Have a look at your Windows Event Log and check if you're seeing any unusual errors. Do you have any aggressive security solutions (Firewall and AV) installed on your host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be...

The Hyper-V. I just uninstalled the feature, reset my all network settings and now it works as new.

I don't know now how to install the Hyper-V without causing such network issues, but it's out of the scope of this question.

After uninstalling Windows Hyper-V feature I regained access to all my networks, both wired and wireless.

In recent Windows 11 build - this problem doesn't exist anymore. I use Hyper-V, I can disable and enable network adapters without problems. It was either bug in Windows 10, or just my broken installation.

Anyway, if anyone stumbles upon similar problem - try to uninstall and re-install Hyper-V, it might help.